# How can I encode/decode shift-jis in elixir?

Tags: character-encoding, elixir, shift-jis

Given text in shift-jis encoding, how can I decode it into Elixir's native UTF-8 encoding, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Codepagex](https://hex.pm/packages/codepagex) library supports this. You just need to figure out what it calls SHIFT_JIS.

Codepagex uses the mappings available from unicode.org. There is one for [shift-jis](https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/OBSOLETE/EASTASIA/JIS/SHIFTJIS.TXT) but it's marked as OBSOLETE, so is not available in Codepagex. However, Microsoft's [CP932](https://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP932.TXT) is also available, which is [effectively](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932_(Microsoft_Windows)) SHIFT_JIS, so you can use that.

#### Config

It's not enabled by default, so you need to enable in in config (and re-compile with `mix deps.compile codepagex --force` if necessary):

```rb
config :codepagex, :encodings, [
  "VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP932"
]
```

#### Encode/Decode

```rb
iex(1)> shift_jis = "VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP932"
"VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP932"
iex(2)> test = Codepagex.from_string!("テスト", shift_jis)
<<131, 101, 131, 88, 131, 103>>
iex(3)> Codepagex.to_string!(test, shift_jis)
"テスト"
```

### Example repo

I made an [example repo](https://github.com/adamu/shift-jis-elixir) where you can see it in action.

Comment: Is this only for Windows? or does running on Mac or Linux require a different module in the `shift_jis` variable?

Comment: @DogEatDog The `Codepagex` library is pure Elixir and platform-independent, AFAIK. `VENDORS/MICSFT/WINDOWS/CP932` is not a module, but the path to mapping file it downloads from unicode.org during compilation.

Comment: Small correction, the mapping files are are not downloaded during compilation, they are included in the distribution: https://github.com/tallakt/codepagex/tree/master/unicode

Comment: this is good to know. thank you